# Why SVR prediction some value

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, svm, prediction

I'm trying to predict stock prices through SVR using python. Given below is the code that I have used,

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR

train= pd.read_csv("ntrain1.csv")
X_train = train.drop("Close Now",1)
Y_train = train["Close Now"]

clf = SVR(kernel= 'rbf', C=100000, gamma=0.2, epsilon = 0.1)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

test= pd.read_csv("ntestbri.csv")
X_test = test.drop("Close Now",1)
Y_test = test["Close Now"]

y_prediksi = clf.predict(X_test)
y_prediksi_series = pd.Series(y_prediksi)
y_prediksi= pd.DataFrame()
y_prediksi["y_prediksi"] = y_prediksi_series
y_prediksi.to_csv("npredksibri3.csv")
rmse = np.sqrt( mean_squared_error( Y_test, y_prediksi ) )
rmse
```

The problem in this code is to generate a prediction with the same value of 4436.021668 and the RMSE value corresponding to the predicted result. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want to do? You want to generate results similar to Y_test? Or want the error to be lower than now? Whats `4436.021668`? Is it the RMSE? or the predicted value of one of the samples?

Comment: Can you upload your data?

Comment: I want the result of the prediction that I get is not the same result and the small rmse value

Comment: and 4436.021668 predict value

Comment: and 4436.021668 predict value

Answer (score 0):

@maulita - not sure what the specific question is but if you are looking to improve your predictor, a best practice is to do the train test split on the training set. This allows you to assess the quality of your predictions and calibrate your predictor prior to loading the test dataset. Hope that helps - Sandeep

Comment: how to split test data split
do you have a related github? @sandeepmohan